# Calling to next middleware after redirect in Express.js

Tags: node.js, testing, express, middleware

I am looking to drive behavior through integration tests on an Express.js middleware. I have encountered an interesting circumstance where the behavior of Express behind the application is not predictable (not by me, anyway).

As a simplified example:

```
var middlewareExample = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.session){
    refreshSession(req.session, function(err, data){
      if(!err){
        res.redirect('/error');
      }
    });
    next();
  }else{
    res.redirect('/authenticate');
  }
};
```

The issue is the call to `next` following the redirect, as it lives outside of the inner function and conditional. I am not certain how Express handles middleware/route calls to `next` or `res.redirect` if they happen to take place before or after one another as seen above.

Manual testing has not revealed any strange behavior, nor has the supertest module. I would like to know if and how Express responds to circumstances such as this. Also, can supertest can be used to expose any potential unwanted behavior. Additionally, if I may, I would like to hear what approaches others would use to test Node/Express middleware in general.

Comment: what are you trying to do? both `res.redirect('/error')` and `next()` can be called in the same request, messing up the whole control flow.

Comment: I'm getting `Can't set headers after they are sent` errors if I try using both.

Comment: @JonathanOng I am trying to reveal through tests any breakage that should be occurring when both functions are allowed to be called in the same request.

Comment: @robertklep Any ideas where and in what ways that error can propogate?

Comment: It will at least show up on console, but I don't think you can check for it from 'the outside' because it's a bit of a moot error: the response (in the form of a redirect) has already been sent to the client at that point.

Comment: After some exhaustive testing, I have confirmed that I was facing a race condition. Since the middleware flow can take some time to process, any action performed on `response`, such as a redirect, will occur before the remaining middleware will process. I created a dummy middleware function which executes `res.send(200)` and placed it after this middleware example. When run live, forces the response to be completed before the redirect can process. In tests, however, the redirect is still faster. I must now inject a delay into the test to prove the race condition.

Comment: Did you finally resolve this? I have race conditions with uploading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are sending two responses in the same request. `next()` is a response, assuming the next handler has a response as well, and so is `res.redirect()`. What you really want is:

```
var middlewareExample = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.session){
    refreshSession(req.session, next);
  }else{
    res.redirect('/authenticate');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue with the below example.

```js
const redirect = () => (res, resp, next) => {
  if (/* redirect condition met */) {
    return resp.status(302).redirect(`https://example.com/${path_logic()}`);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
}

app.use(redirect());
app.get('*', static('built/project/code'));
```

I wasnt able to find anything talking about redirects *not* working in the `.use` method. But apparently it is not allowed.

Here is my solution.

```js
const redirect = () => (res, resp, next) => {
  if (/* redirect condition met */) {
    return resp.status(302).redirect(`https://example.com/${path_logic()}`);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
}

app.get('*', [
  redirect(),
  static('built/project/code')
]);
```

The only logic difference here is the redirection function only seem to work when combined with a request handler (`.get` `.post` etc), but not `.use`.